# SystemState.PhoneSignalStrength in WinCE

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce

Am I right in thinking that the below will not work on a WinCE 6 device?

```
int signal = SystemState.PhoneSignalStrength;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct.  [The SystemState class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.status.systemstate.aspx) is part of the Microsoft.WindowsMobile namespace which, as the name suggests, is only in Windows Mobile devices.  It uses the [State and Notification Broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb154491.aspx) under the hood, which doesn't exist in standard Windows CE builds.